# The non negativity of the derivatives of non polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

So I have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is almost everywhere not a polynomial. In a proof I am currently trying to understand, they state that for any derivative I can find an $x_k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
    f^{(k)}(x_k) \neq 0 \ \ \ \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.
\end{equation}

I see where this statement is coming from, but I need help with actually proving it or maybe someone knows some literature where I can find this statement.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What happens if there is a $k$ for which no such $x_k$ exists?

Comment: @geetha290krm What do you mean? This is what I am trying to prove! In this proof which I am trying to understand, they just claim that there isn't such a $k$.

Comment: Do you know what a  contrapositive is?

Comment: You mean that I just assume that for one $k$, $f^{k}(x)=0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
With this I could follow $f^{k-1}(x)=c \in \mathbb{R}$ and therefore $f$ some polynomial?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: Okay, thank you.